# In Magento, how can I resize the product list view to be much smaller and more concise?

Tags: html, css, magento

Basically, my problem is pretty straight forward.  Currently, the way magento displays products in list view is far too large for my needs.  It utilizes a much larger image than I'd like, and each product listed takes up a large amount of space.  What I would like is to resize the listing so that each product is basically a single line or two that includes a very small thumbnail image on the left, the title, the short description and finally the price.  If I can list my products this way, many more will be able to fit on a single page in a concise manner (which is what I need).

For reference, the way the site currently displays products in list view can be seen here with a couple test products: http://soundcherry.com/index.php/sound-effects.html

Is there any way for me to achieve the results I'm looking for?  I'm not sure which files to modify or what exactly to change.  I've been doing as much research as I can, but I'm somewhat of an amateur (especially with coding of any kind) and I haven't been able to figure it out.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was going to comment but it didn't fit

Edit both Template files and css files

for example on style.css

(which is here on your host http://soundcherry.com/skin/frontend/default/f002/css/styles.css)

on line 799 change padding:12px 10px; to padding:1px 2px;
then hard refresh (Ctrl+F5) and see the result
or on the same file on line 801 you can change margin:0 0 10px; to margin:0 0 2px;
and change width and height to width:80px; height:80px;
you can also add a line after line 801 to force resize those images like this:
.products-list .product-image img { width:80px; height:80px; }

but you should change < img > dimension in your Template files,

search for your template folder and when you find the file edit width= and height= in `< img >` tag

#### NOTE If you're using Firefox right-click on where you want to change and click Inspect Element, interact with the left box to select the element you want visually and then you will find out which line is that class or id on the right box of Inspector, id is unique and is shown by #id_name { } and class is shown like this .class_name { }

### EDIT after comment

for that you should edit your template files, (they are html files with .Phtml file extension located im /template/ folders) find the file you need to change and change it

check this page out as it have many useful information

[Click Here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/0_-_theming_in_magento/designing-for-magento)

### EDIT 2

i have worked with other systems but not magento

i don't know which file exactly it is i think it might be products.phtml or something in your template folder

the code is something like this

```
    <div class="f-fix">
    <h2 class="product-name"><a href="{$link}" title="{$title}">{$title}</a></h2>
    <div class="price-box"><span class="regular-price" id="product-price-3"><span class="price">{$price}</span></span></div>
    <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span>{$availability}</span></p>
    <div class="desc std">{$desc}<a href="{$link}" title="{$title}" class="link-learn">Learn More</a>
    </div><ul class="add-to-links"><li><a href="{$wishlist}" class="link-wishlist">Add to Wishlist</a></li>
    <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="{$compare}" class="link-compare">Add to Compare</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

as < div > and < p > tags (which may appear such as < div class="desc dtd" > ) are block elements, you should either apply style="display:inline-block" to them this can be applied like this

```
<p class="availability out-of-stock" style="display:inline-block">
```

or you can apply a new class by space to current tag like this

```
                                    |HERE|
<p class="availability out-of-stock new_class">
```

and then define this class in your style.css like this

```
.new_class { display:inline-block; }
```

or remove the < div > < /div > and < p > < /p > tags to make them all apear in a single line, something like:

```
    <div class="f-fix">
    <h2 class="product-name"><a href="{$link}" title="{$title}">{$title}</a></h2>
    <span class="regular-price" id="product-price-3"><span class="price">{$price}</span></span>
    <span style="availability out-of-stock">{$availability}</span>
    {$desc}<a href="{$link}" title="{$title}" class="link-learn">Learn More</a>
    <a class="add-to-links" href="{$wishlist}" class="link-wishlist">Add to Wishlist</a>
    <span class="separator">|</span> <a href="{$compare}" class="link-compare">Add to Compare</a>
    </div>
```

i think maybe it is a little soon for you to edit such scripts templates, please consider reading html and css tutorials and the page i gave you first

[HTML Toturial](http://www.w3schools.com/html/)

[CSS Toturial](http://www.w3schools.com/css/)

Plus this Magento design guide:

[Magento Design Guide](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/0_-_theming_in_magento/designing-for-magento)

i know it is not fun at the moment , but trust me its ***SO EASY (but you're trying to start with a complicated script and template, please google for simple examples to start learning CSS and HTML)***  and once you've learned CSS and HTML you will enjoy them so much

Comment: First, let me thank you for answering my question.  Your information has been very helpful and has brought me the closest I've been so far to what I'm trying to achieve.  So, thank you.  

Changing the padding on line 799 is helpful as it removes some minor spacing.  The image resizing seems to work perfectly as well.  But, I'm still having a few issues.

How can I get the listings to display as a single line of text rather than the title, stock, price, etc...  All being on different lines?

Comment: @MAC for that you should change template file check my edit above

Comment: I know it's asking a lot, but could you be slightly more specific about which template file I need to modify as well as what I should be looking for to actually change?  

I've been going through the template files I think I need to change, but I'm not finding what I need...  : /

Comment: @MAC one of the files contains your desired code, i updated my answer hope it can help

Comment: Thank you so much.  I'll do my best to learn more and to follow your instructions.  Again, thank you for taking so much time to help me!